# Handled Exceptions and Transaction Rollback

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a Custom ActionFilterAttribute, which starts a `NHibernate Session.Transaction`.

I was wondering when an exception is handled in the Action before hand, how can i get it on `ActionExceutedContext`,   so as to avoid it executing the transaction commit and instead call a rollback. It works fine if exception is unhandled. Need a way out for the handled ones. I don't want to write a rollback, everywhere i handle the exception.

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        _transactionHelper.BeginTransaction();
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    } 


public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.Exception == null)
            _transactionHelper.Commit();

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could throw a new exception in your catch block that wraps the original exception:

```
try
{
    var x = 1 / 0;
}
catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
{
    // handle and allow transaction to commit
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // handle and throw new exception so that transaction is rolled back in filter
    throw new ExceptionCaughtInActionException(ex); // custom exception wrapper
}
```

With this approach your filter can also do some logging. However, in my opinion it is better to handle the transaction in the action method. It can be repetitive but I find that it's much more readable and allows better control of transaction boundaries.

Comment: Thanks! But as you said, I should then better write the rollback in my action. 
Still i am looking for a better alternative.